# Hard reset and now I've lost an app - which is no longer on MS Store

Tags: apps

As subject - I did a hard reset and I've completely lost an app. I backed up before the reset, but because the app is no longer in the store, it won't restore. Is there any way to restore the app? It's a bus pass app which the operator no longer supports, but can still be used to purchase tickets, any thoughts? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Apps are required to be on store unless you have unlocked for development, then is loaded through USB.

Comment: As I thought. Many thanks for your response

Comment: please consider maring this as the accepted answer if it did answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

I think the app is still there but your phone doesn't meet it minimum requirements anymore. 
Try going to the developers website and check for infos, or log into the Store from a computer then search for that app and eventually its minimum requirements.